# Refreshing a html table which has a progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, spring-mvc, progress-bar

I have a requirement which is nothing but progress bar inside a table column which should be active. I will have plenty of bootstrap progress bar(Say some 10) and I am using spring mvc in server side. Now the problem is I don't know how to update the progress bar constantly(Say some every 10secs) without refreshing the entire page, to be more precise I want the html table to be refreshed every 10 secs, it should hit the server and the value of the progress bar should be 
applied to the progress bar inside the html table.

Can some one please suggest how to do this requirement, I am really in need of help and any example links which would actually help me to achieve this. I am
not expert in javascript/ajax( I guess its possible to achieve this using ajax, I could not find any examples in google either). If this is achievable using 
javascript(nor ajax) any example links would actually help me a lot. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the javascript side you would have a js function making a $.ajax call

```
function getProgress(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "/myurl",
    success : function(data){
      //TODO here update your progressbar data=XX returned by spring
      if(data!=100){
         setTimeout(getProgress,10000);//reschedule again until job finished
      }
    }
  })
}
setTimeout(getProgress,10000);
```

on the spring side :

in a controller you will return the progress :

```
@RequestMapping("/myurl")
public @ResponseBody String getProgrees(){
  //TODO business logic
  return "XX";//0-100
}
```

Comment: Jpprade Thanks :) I will try this out and let you know , By the way I have a doubt ? What if I have some 10 progress bar in a single html page, how would I return 10 values(from spring) and assign it to the progress bar ?

Comment: In this cas you can return a HashMap<String,String> instead of string. You must have jackson (1.9 for spring <3.2 )  in your classpath to have the map serialized to json. Then if in your map you add a value like this : map.put("progress1","12"); you can retrieve it in JS just with : data.progress1

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Your code works perfectly fine :) you saved my time :) BTW for multiple progress bar i have returned "10*10*10" from my spring controller and used the split() method of javascript to convert it as array of string and assigned it to each of the progress bar !! I just want to make it simple , so opted for this solution of mine !! :) Anyways thanks a lot and i have rated your answer as solution , Have a great day :)